# Is there any possible way to hide External Libraries from Project View in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to hide the External Libraries section.
[image]

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Could you please describe your use case? Why do you need to hide it?

Comment: Just want to have a simpler project view. Spend very less time going about all the external jars I have, so thought of hiding it in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: So, you may try to use scopes: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by simply switching [Project Files] from [Project] to [Project Files], just like I did in following picture:

[image]